# With next-auth, avoid showing sign in page as soon as there is no connection?

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I am using next-auth for authentication of my web app. As soon as the internet connection is lost and the visibility of the page change (next-auth has an event listener on `onvisibilitychange` to refresh the session as soon as that happens), then the browser redirects to the sign in page (assuming the credentials are not valid anymore).

Is there a way to prevent this?